# Emacs hang after installing gtk3 in windows 7

Tags: windows, emacs, gtk3, freeze

I recently decided to use emacs as I am starting to learn common lisp. But here is a problem that I feel that I must have done something wrong. After googling around for the past several hours,  I still couldn't figure out why.

I am using windows 7. Installing the most recent emacs (24.5) with quicklisp, slime, sbcl etc are all fine. Then I started to install gtk+3 according to http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php. And it went well: I can run gtk3-demo. The problem is that after I put the path in the system environment, emacs was not responsive anymore: When I run runemacs.exe, it starts a window, then hang with a blank window (the menu appears). It can start fine after I remove the /dir-to-gtk-bin/ from the path.

I believe that there must be something wrong with my system setup, since emacs should work smoothly with gtk+ devleopment. Could you please give me a hint on where to start checking? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Please try starting it from `cmd.exe`. You may get some useful output in that window.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris. I have tried the suggestion. For a moment, I thought that I had pinpoint the problem to permission issue. But after repetitive trying, the following are the results:

Comment: Sorry, typed return key before I finished (still new to the forum): 1. I can reproduce the results on two machines, one is my office desktop running windows 7 enterprise, the other is my home laptop running windows 7 home premium; 2. I run the process using cmd, windows power shell, and clicking the icon directly from the windows, with or without admin permission; 3. The emacs always hang after putting in the path of gtk/bin, and come back after removing it; 4. Emacs can run without the windows (under -nw option); 5. After I put the emacs/bin in the path, I got the following output.

Comment: (emacs.exe:5132): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call t_type_init(). The next line says: (emacs.exe:5132): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed. I googled online and there are no such symptom reported before. Since these outcome are robust across two different machines under different windows setup, I tend to think that this is not accidental. But given that there were no reports on this, I am still at a loss on the direction to go at the moment. I am totally new to emacs: Does emacs also use gtk? Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Emacs can be compiled against GTK+. It's likely that the Windows version is. But I would expect it to be statically linked, so I'm not sure why installing another version would cause problems. You might want to submit this to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ for better results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris. I also ran addpm.exe and it didn't work. So far I think it is more of an emacs in windows problem, since I also did the same in ubuntu using a VM and everything worked perfectly there. I was just thinking about posting to emacs help mailing list, but surely emacs.stachexchange.com will be better. Again thanks.

Comment: I upgraded my emacs 24.2 (2013) to emacs 24.5 (2016) on windows7, and the new emacs hangs on first command M-x R-[hang]mode.  Going back to older version for now.